# Woocommerce callback function is not getting called

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Here is my code :

```
 add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'mojo_abc_init', 0 );
function mojo_abc_init() {
...

include_once( 'woocommerce-abc.php' );

...
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'mojo_add_abc_gateway' );
function mojo_add_abc_gateway( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'MOJO_ABC';
    return $methods;
}
...
}
```

My woocommerce-abc.php file :

```
class MOJO_ABC extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
   function __construct() {

       ...

       add_action('woocommerce_api_mojo_abc', array($this, 'check_abc_response'));

      ...
   }

   /* callback function */
   function check_abc_response(){

    /* code */
    wp_die();
   }

}
```

Now my problem is my callback function is not getting called. The url is http://site_url/wc-api/MOJO_ABC .

Instead the screen is showing just 1 and there is nothing in the debug logs also indicating any problem with the code.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I would try initializing your plugin on the `woocommerce_loaded` hook. But also, are you adding your gateway via the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` filter? You didn't show that part of your code.

Comment: @helgatheviking I am adding my gateway via the `woocomerce_available_payment_gateways` filter. I have edited the code. Anyways I was able to solve the issue.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by disabling all plugins and then adding them one by one with my plugin and checking the debug logs of the woocommerce.

I found that one of the other plugin had some bugs and that is what was interfering with my hook to get registered properly and hence not being called. I disabled that plugin only and it started working like a charm. I have notified the plugin developer of the issue for now.

For debugging, you should do some things that helped me find the issue:

1. Enable the debug mode of wordpress in wp-config.php file:
   `

   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
   // Disable display of errors and warnings
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
   @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

`

2.Add log functionality in plugin to write logs in debug file to check the flow of your code and other things :
 Add this code in your constructor at the start :-
 `

```
if (!function_exists('write_log')) {
        function write_log ( $log )  {
          if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
            if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
              error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
            } else {
              error_log( $log );
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

`<br>
And write logs by`write.log("abc")`or`write.log($var)`.

This way you can rule out possibilities of errors in your workflow and focus on what other things that could have caused the issue.